# Standard Deviation outputting as 0, how to fix?

Tags: arrays, eclipse, standard-deviation

My Standard deviation in this program is outputting as 0 and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've been stuck on this for hours, please help.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to calculate?");
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    double a[] = new double[(int) n];       // casting n to a double
    double sum = 0.0;
    double sd = 0.0;

    System.out.println("Fill in the values for all " + n + " numbers.");
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }

    double average = sum/a.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
           a[i] = Math.pow((a[i]-average),2);       // need help here
    }


    System.out.println("The Mean of the " + n +" numbers is " + average);
    System.out.println("The Standard Deviation of the " + n + " numbers is " + sd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QuoRQE)

Also I have modified your code which should work now and give you correct result.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to calculate?");
    int n = scan.nextInt();

    double a[] = new double[(int) n];       // casting n to a double
    double sum = 0.0;
    double sqrSum = 0.0;
    double sd = 0.0;

    System.out.println("Fill in the values for all " + n + " numbers.");
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }

    double average = sum/a.length;

    //Perform the Sum of (value-avg)^2
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++)
    {
        sqrSum = sqrSum + Math.pow( a[i] - average, 2);
    }
    sd = Math.sqrt(sqrSum / (a.length - 1));


    System.out.println("The Mean of the " + n +" numbers is " + average);
    System.out.println("The Standard Deviation of the " + n + " numbers is " + sd);
}
```

Comment: I don't even know what LINQ is. Im' just trying to figure out why my standard deviation is outputting 0.......

Comment: @RyanHorner I have modified my answer. As you did not know about LINQ so i have removed the LINQ parts and added the missing logic for you.

Comment: Thanks for updating! But I'm still getting incorrect results. I entered 100, 200, and 300 and it said that the standard deviation of those 3 numbers is 81.64965809277261

Comment: I need the result to be the Standard Deviation, not the Population Standard Deviation. I didn't even know these were two different things. So I learned something important but still didn't solve my issue xD. Thank you though!!

Comment: @RyanHorner I have updated the answer. change "sd = Math.sqrt(sqrSum / a.length);" to "sd = Math.sqrt(sqrSum / a.length - 1);". It will give Standard Deviation.

Comment: i replaced that line and I'm still getting 81.64965809277261 when I enter 100, 200, and 300. I copied your entire updated answer and it's still the same 81.64965809277261 :(

Comment: i figured it out. I was missing a pair of parenthesis around a.length - 1. After I put some around that the program works perfectly now :D thank you for all your input Nick!

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. I updated the answer with that just in case anyone need it. Can you please mark it as answer if it works for you. Cheers.